# Indexing of Object keys in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have this structure

```
{
    "_id": "willwill",
    "rental": {
        "hitchhikergalaxy": {[...]},
        "animalfarm": {[..]}
    }
}
```

Which `[..]` is a embedded document storing the details of the rental (and the exactly same data also exists on another collection) and the `rental` Object's keys are `_id` of the `book` collection.

How do I `ensureIndex()` this query?

```
db.users.find({"rental.animalfarm": {'$exists': true}})
```

(I use MongoDB on PHP, but the example above is in JavaScript)

Comment: so you want to confirm there is an index on the animalfarm value?

Comment: I need to know which user have a specific book in their rental list. A book may exists in multiple users' list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to think about refactoring the document such that:

```
"rental": 
  [
     { "name":"hitchikergalaxy", "attributes": { your stuff } },
     { "name":"animalfarm", "attributes": { your stuff } }
  ]
```

Now you have a path to ensureIndex  "rental.name"

You can further find all documents where any user rented animalfarm using:

```
db.users.find( { "rental.name": "animalfarm" } )
```

I've been down the path of using data as keys/names -- and it always seems to make things more complicated than they need to be.